# Python, prime number checker

Tags: python, numbers, primes

Hi i'm making a function that checks if a number is a prime or not but its telling me that 9 is a prime.

```
def eprimo(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False
    if num == 2:
        return True
    else:
        for div in range(2,num):
            if num % div == 0:
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Step through your code. What have you tried?

Comment: Just as an efficiency note you only need to test from 2 to num/2

Comment: `(num ** .5) +1` or math.sqrt(num)+1 actually.

Comment: protip: on the first line of `eprimo` put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` - [here](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/) is a pretty decent tutorial if you need it.

Comment: @Synthetica one of my most favorite "hacks" - getting the square root without having to use `math.sqrt()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to return from the first iteration of that for loop whether you're done checking or not.  You shouldn't return from inside the loop unless the number is definitely not prime.  Remove the `else` and only return `True` if the loop finishes.

```
def eprimo(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False
    if num == 2:
        return True
    else:
        for div in range(2,num):
            if num % div == 0:
                return False
        return True
```

Optimization side note: You really don't need to check all the divisor candidates up to `num`.  You only need to check up to the square root of `num`.

Answer (score 6):

Your `for` loop exits right after the first iteration when it checks whether your number is divisible by 2. If your number is even, it will return `False`; otherwise, it will return `True`.

The solution is not to return `True` immediately; wait for the end of all the iterations in the loop instead:

```
for div in range(2, num):
    if num % div == 0:
        return False
return True
```

Alternatively, use the `all()` construct:

```
return all(num % div != 0 for div in range(2, num))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing all divisors in range(2,num), you could extract the test for even numbers and then loop only on the odd numbers. Additionally, as Bill the Lizard suggests, you could stop at the square root of num. This will be twice as fast:

```
def eprimo(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False
    if num % 2 == 0:
        return num == 2
    div = 3
    while div * div <= num:
        if num % div == 0:
            return False
        div += 2
    return True
```